# ANGULAR Iterate over an Array within a Model

Tags: arrays, angular, ngfor

**Synopsis:**
I am trying to iterate over an array that is returned as part of an object. The object has three properties 2 string,  1 array.  I want to iterate over the array i my html but can't seem to get it to populate.  I can get both strings to show, but cannot figure out how to iterate the inner array for values.

**Policy.ts**

```
import { Document } from './Document';

export interface Policy {
  insuredName: string;
  policyNumber: string;
  documents: Document[];
}
```

**Document.ts**

```
export interface Document {
    url: string,
    docType: string
  }
```

I bind the model("policy") in my parent component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  policy: any = {};

  constructor(private policyService: PolicyService, private alertify: AlertifyService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
loadPolicy() {
    this.policyService.getPolicy(this.policy.policyNumber).subscribe((res) => {
      this.policy.insuredName = res.insuredName;
      this.policy.policyNumber = res.policyNumber;
      this.documents = res.documents;


    }, error => {
      this.alertify.error(error);
    })
  }
```

I pass the data to my child component

**Search.component.html**

```
<app-documentList [policy]=policy></app-documentList>
```

and then bind it in the child

```
export class DocumentListComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() policy: Policy;

  ngOnInit() {

  }
```

but when I finally try the iteration all I get is the first property (insuredName) and nothing for the *ngFor

```
<div>
  <div class="test">

    <p>{{policy.insuredName}}</p>
    <h2 *ngFor="let doc of policy.documents">{{doc.url}}</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you forget the quotation marks on the policy attribute of the child on the app selector? It should be [policy] = "policy"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing `this.documents = res.documents;` with `this.policy.documents = res.documents;`.

Looks like you are binding the result to a wrong variable.

Also you might not have to assign values manually. You could do the following

```js
import { Policy } from './Policy';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  policy: Policy = {};

  constructor(private policyService: PolicyService, private alertify: AlertifyService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  loadPolicy() {
    this.policyService.getPolicy(this.policy.policyNumber).subscribe((res: Policy) => {
      this.policy = res;
    }, error => {
      this.alertify.error(error);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Both suggestions worked ... thank you for helping me find my daily "really I missed that?!?!?" moment.